# how to set hanko on signature document

Tags: docusignapi

Does anyone know how to set hanko field (印鑑フィールド) show on signature document by using Docusign API.

I had read Docusign API document but I didn't find the appropriate parameter for it.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Which DocuSign API document did you read that discussed this feature?  Do you have a link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google reveals:

There is a Nov 2015 press release: [DocuSign and Shachihata to Bring Hanko into the Digital Age](https://www.docusign.com/press-releases/docusign-and-shachihata-to-bring-hanko-into-the-digital-age)

Also, Hanko work by DocuSign was briefly discussed by a DocuSign executive in an interview in June 2016.

However, as of this writing, there has not been any product announcements related to Hanko.

If you're interested in testing new DocuSign features, please let your account manager know.

Comment: Thanks for your answer